# Play sound when click on EventListner javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to run a sound when clicking on a dynamically created

But i get the error Object has no method. The tutorials i have found only call elementById
but since this is a class im using the eventlistner.

This is what i have for now.

```
function AddEvent(){ 
    var addClass= document.getElementsByClassName("add"); 
    addClass=addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
    addClass.addEventListener("click", playsound, true); 

    function playsound() { 

        var mySound = src="wav/add.wav"
        mySound.play(); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Object in javascript has no method play unless you use some script to do the job.i guess that's where you get the error 'Object has no method'.

Comment: @bradciven I looked at w3school, and they are using a .play method.
Am I wrong ?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp

Comment: Yes. the object they're using `play()` on refers to a Video object.

Comment: @BenM Is there a methos for Audio ?

Comment: Sure, see my answer and jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `audio` element in HTML 5, hide it, and then use JavaScript / jQuery to manipulate it. So your HTML would look something like:

```
<audio id="mySound">
    <source src="add.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="add.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And then you can use the following JS:

```
function AddEvent()
{ 
    var addClass = document.getElementsByClassName("add"); 
    addClass = addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
    addClass.addEventListener("click", function() {  
        document.getElementById('mySound').play();
    }, true); 
}
```

You can see a working [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MztHp/). You should be advised that this uses HTML 5 though, so IE < 9 won't support this.

Comment: Well I actually got it work that way, I just didn't want to add anything to the html file, just do everything with JavaScript. But i maybe can create the audio ID dynamically ? now you gave me an idea here. :)

Comment: You could indeed create the element dynamically. Using jQuery would be your best option, but this is the way forward :)

Comment: I would love to use Jquery but its for studying purpose, so strict JS for the moment, Thanks anyhow, you got me in the right way :)